# Using bypass capacitors to reduce voltage spikes and noise causing I2C read/write errors

Tags: i2c, bit-bang

I'm trying to communicate with an old i2c device and I'm getting wrong read values, and possibly even some incorrect write values too.

My logic analyzer shows random highs in the middle of a low.

This happens mostly on software i2c but I get incorrect reads on the hardware i2c too.

What could cause these spikes?

Here's an illustration. Look at the end of the second byte (C0)
[image]

**Edit:** This seems very related: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=223056

Comment: I don't know how to use Rpi software I2c, but hardware I2c has caused me enough headache these couple of years.  So I gave up and wait for Rp4 and stretech10.  I also don't use logic analyzer, because the logic analyzer hides way ugly glitches, which scope makes them transparent. Yes, I know there are dual mode analyzer/scope, and my cheap socpe can also analyze,a do realtime transofrms, report back even FFT figures, not to mention other trivial algebric calculations.  Things are moving too fast to catch up.  SuperTem that I have been using for UART for years can now even do I2C jobs, ... :)

Comment: I noticed that for a couple of I2C devices, the vendors usually do tricks to remove noisy, fluctuating read data, such as taking moving average, trim max min etc.  Others use smart digital filters, ...

Comment: Damn bro you gonna answer all my questions? haha. For real though, I'm thiking of trying other ARM linux boards or something. I need a reliable i2c master.

Comment: Or Rpi as a stupid and weak master, making greedy wishes to the mighty Aladdin Lamp slave, the STM32 Blue Pill, :)

Comment: But I need a Linux board

Comment: But there are too many "real" linux boards running Ubantu/Debian out there for you to pick.  I once thought of switching back to Ubantu, but I recently heard that Google has turned to Debian, so the huge Google fan will follow - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghHE_kVWXxM

Comment: Yes but will they also have i2c problems? That's my biggest concern

Comment: Well, if the real linux boards have I2C problems, the fake board has 10 times more.  
And you might consider SparkFun Qwiic Adapter  https://www.sparkfun.com/qwiic

Comment: And if you are using TSX010n based logical level converters, your may try TSB010n which seems more stable.  Adafruit in the beginning recommended TSX, but now they are selling TSB, perhaps for a reason.  Just brainstorming, most likely not solving any problem.

Comment: I think I've solved the problem. I need to more testing, but a 1uF cap between GND and 3V on the RPi seems to solve my problems. Yet to be confirmed.

Comment: Oh my goodness, isn't that simple? You reminded me a couple of months ago, when I played with ESP8266-12 using USB/TTL cable to power the ESP8266 board.  I often heard complaints about ESP8266 intermittently auto resetting.  The problem finally solved more or less by adding a big cap 1,000 uF to by pass the power supply at the point very near the ESP chip.  My lesson learnt is that if your power/signal source is too far from the VIP device, add a big cap (don't know why 10u and 0.1 u combination).  So I always spend more money to buy a tantalum cap, never the cheap looking mud like discs）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to bridge the RPi GND and 3v using a cap.

I used a 1uF cap.

Comment: I suspect the root cause of most Pi I2C problems can be traced to an electrical fault, e.g.  poor wiring, loose wiring, out of I2C spec wiring etc.

Comment: Standard bypass/decoupling caps are 10uF tantalum and 0.1 ceramic, near device, and much bigger bypass, 100uF or larger electrolyte at PSU.  I use Guinness Record breaking value of 10,000 uF. :)

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

I2C device reading writing errors problem. How to solve it?

***Answer***

There are many reasons causing reading and writing errors.  To name a few:

1. Wires too long (more than 30cm) and not twisted.  A suggestion is to use twisted cable Cat 5 to reduce mains EMI noise picking up,
2. I2C speed too high. A suggestion it to start testing a low speed, such as 100kHz,
3. Pullup overloading Rpi which already has 1k8 pull up.  A suggestion is to remove ALL pullups of the I2C devices,
4. Rpi I2C circuit too noisy.  A suggestion is to use logical level converters such as TXS010n, TXB010n to step up 3V3 signal to 5V (high level means low risk of noise etc problem)
5. PSU dirty.  A suggestion is to place standard bypass/decoupling cpas 10u tantalum and 0.1 ceramic near the device and also near the Rpi mciro USB connector.

[image: rpi psu cap]

[image: ads1115 pullup removal]

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[I2C Manual - Application Note AN10216-01 - NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10216.pdf)

[I2C Bus Pullup Resistor Calculation - Application Report SLVA689–February 2015 - TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf)

[Clean Power for Every IC, Part 1: Understanding Bypass Capacitors - Robert Keim, AAC 2015sep21](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/clean-power-for-every-ic-part-1-understanding-bypass-capacitors/)

[Clean Power for Every IC, Part 2: Choosing and Using Your Bypass Capacitors - Robert Keim. AAC 2015sep27](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/clean-power-for-every-ic-part-2-choosing-and-using-your-bypass-capacitors/)

> ***Introduction***
>
> It is not inconceivable that a dedicated, successful engineering
>   student would graduate from college knowing almost nothing about one
>   of the most pervasive and important components found in real circuits:
>   the bypass capacitor. Even experienced engineers may not fully
>   understand why they *include **0.1 µF** ceramic capacitors next to every
>   power pin of every IC in every circuit board they design.* This article
>   provides information that will help you to understand why bypass
>   capacitors are necessary and how they improve circuit performance, and
>   a follow-up article will focus on details related to choosing bypass
>   capacitors and the PCB layout techniques that maximize their efficacy.
>
> ...
>
> ***Solution***
>
> it is convenient that such a serious problem can be effectively
>   resolved with a simple, widely available component. But why the
>   capacitor? A straightforward explanation is the following: A capacitor
>   stores charge that can be supplied to the IC with very low series
>   resistance and very low series inductance. Thus, transient currents
>   can be supplied from the bypass capacitor (through minimal resistance
>   and inductance) instead of from the power line (through comparatively
>   large resistance and inductance). To better understand this, we need
>   to review some basic concepts related to how a capacitor affects a
>   circuit.
>
> First, though, a brief note about terminology: The components
>   discussed in this article are regularly referred to as both “***bypass***
>   ***capacitors***” and “***decoupling capacitors***.” There is a subtle distinction
>   here—“decoupling” refers to reducing the degree to which one part of a
>   circuit influences another, and “bypass” refers to providing a
>   low-impedance path that allows noise to “pass by” an IC on its way to
>   the ground node. Both terms can be correctly used because a
>   bypass/decoupling capacitor accomplishes both tasks. In this article,
>   however, “bypass capacitor” is favored in order to avoid confusion
>   with a series decoupling capacitor used to block the DC component of a
>   signal.
>
> ***A Standard Approach***
>
> The foregoing analysis helps us to understand a classic bypassing
>   scheme:
>
> ***a 10 µF capacitor within an inch or two of the IC,*** and
>
> ***a 0.1 µF ceramic capacitor as close to the power pin as possible***:
>
> The larger capacitor smooths out lower-frequency variations in the
>   supply voltage, and the smaller capacitor more effectively filters out
>   high-frequency noise on the power line.
>
> If we incorporate these bypass capacitors into the 8-inverter
>   simulation discussed above, the ringing is eliminated and the
>   magnitude of the voltage disturbance is reduced from ***1 mV to 20 µV***,
>   ...

***Update 2019may04hkt0846***

Grounding is also a problem.  See the ADXL346 Datasheet's suggestion below.

[image: ADXL345 grounding]

Comment: @tifong01 where were you eaaarlieeeeerrrrrr

Comment: What do you mean?  I have been around all the time.

Comment: with all this information. I needed it before haha

Comment: Well, I usually suggest things to newbies only AFTER they have made stupid mistakes.  This way they learn harder but remember important things longer.  And otherwise they won't bother to listen to the old guy. :)  I heard that you have a logic analyzer, so I guess you should have more advanced knowledge than a poor hobbyist like me - therefore no suggestions needed before or after.

Comment: Having a logic analyzer =/= Having electrical engineering knowledge
Having a logic analyzer == Reading data protocol

Comment: Yes, you win. You remind me a friend of mine who was working in uni EE dept. He studied applied statistics before doing research in mobile stuff: 1G analog, 2G GSM/TDMA, 3G UTMS, 4G LTE, ... He is sort of a protocol guy, but for sure a fake EE guy, because he did not know how to use a multimeter, not to mention a scope! :) I have not seen him for a long while, not sure if he has already learned how to use a multimeter, and now playing with 5G in Huawei, ZTE, Nokia, Samsung, or Ericsson.