# RpiZero Power Supply through 40 pin Power/GPIO Header or microUSB connector

Tags: power, pi-zero

As the title states I want to power my pi-zero with an adafruit powerboost 1000. I have looked into ways to do this and it seems there are 2 possibilities:

- Use the USB output of the powerboost to power the pi-zero through it's intended usb port. However this takes up some space.
- Use the expansion header of the pi-zero, specifically the 5v and the ground pins. This seems to be more compact.

I'd prefer option 2, but I also read that the usb option is safer since it has a fuse to protect the pi. However I think that doesn't apply to the pi-zero right?

So my question to you is am I correct that these 2 options are possible and are there some other up/downsides to either that I missed?

Comment: The Pi Zero has no protection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question***

> USB option is safer since it has a fuse to protect the pi. However I
>   think that doesn't apply to the pi-zero right?

***Answer***

> Yes, RpiZero does not have poly fuse protection.  So I added poly fuse
>   and also slow blow fuse myself.
>
> I prefer to apply power at the micro USB connector, because it is easy
>   to do maintenance work like measuring voltage levels, modifying PSU
>   with UPS etc.  Applying power to the 40 pin Power/GPIO DuPont male
>   plug is bit risky, because careless shorting 5V, 3V3 power pins to
>   ground or GPIO pins might damage something.

[image: rpi zero psu]

[image: rpi zero psu]

[image: lipo power bank]

***References***

[Rpi PSU by pass capacitors to reduce noise problems](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98116/random-i2c-sda-spikes-bit-flip)

[Clean Power for Every IC, Part 1: Understanding Bypass Capacitors - Robert Keim, AAC 2015sep21](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/clean-power-for-every-ic-part-1-understanding-bypass-capacitors/)

[Clean Power for Every IC, Part 2: Choosing and Using Your Bypass Capacitors - Robert Keim. AAC 2015sep27](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/clean-power-for-every-ic-part-2-choosing-and-using-your-bypass-capacitors/)

[Viability of using a USB power bank as a UPS?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=186091)