# Is it safe to put capacitor on 3v3 pin of raspberry

Tags: pi-3, gpio, electronics

I am going to use [INA220](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina220.pdf) ic for current monitoring, and the datasheet says:

> Use a 0.1-μF ceramic capacitor for power-supply bypassing, placed as closely as possible to the supply and ground pins.

So the question is can i use the capacitor since i am pulling current from 3v3 pin of rpi to use this ic, is it safe for long term?

Comment: Hi @Animesh Sahu, Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah let me see. Standard EE practice is to use 0.1uF and 10uF. For motor, servo, and solenoids, I use 100uF to 10,000uF. I NEVER TOUCH the Rpi's 40 pin connector 3V3 and 5V power pins. I ALWAYS use cheapy, external, temperature and current limiting/short circuit protected power supplies: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98116/random-i2c-sda-spikes-bit-flip

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98715/connecting-pi-zero-w-to-adafruit-powerboost-1000-through-extension-header-or-usb/98733#98733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly safe - this is recommended practice. Virtually all external devices (including HATs) will have similar capacitors.

It will have no detectable impact on the Pi.